# SLF4J returns false for isDebugEnabled() when logger level = DEBUG

Tags: maven, log4j, slf4j

I have a peculiar problem.

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {  
    logger.debug("Message=\"About to get the application details\" GroupID={}", iGroupID);  
}
```

I have this code and when check the logger. The level of `logger = DEBUG`, but the method `logger.isDebugEnabled()` simply returns false.

I'm using SLF4J and Maven to add dependencies.

Comment: You mentioned "when check the logger". How do you check the logger? how do you know that the level is `DEBUG`?

Comment: You'll have to show us some more info. Your `log4j.properties` file would be nice to see and also where in the project structure you have added it.

Comment: BTW, you're doing it wrong. The message placeholder syntax using {} is used so that you don't have to wrap your statements with isXyzEnabled() checks. That's the whole point of using slf4j!

Comment: Hi Isaac,  I ran it from eclipse and I hope I could show the variable snapshot while I was debugging it.  Anyways, the problem is solved. I checked the log4j.xml and it turns out that i set the threshold attribute in the parent node to INFO. Stupid of me. Thanks though

Comment: Got any solution ?